# DirectX10 Texture from char vector

Tags: directx, png, char, textures

I have a C++ server application that receives .png images from a client Android application. The connection uses sockets and receives the image data as char's and stores it in a vector.

```
std::vector<char> vec;
```

The application then needs to display the images on screen using directx10, I know you can manually fill textures but that would mean I would need to parse the png file. My question is is there anyway other way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[D3DX10CreateTextureFromMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb172672%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).